# Java Convert strange string to Burmese language string

Tags: java, utf-8, fonts, utf

Hi my example code is like ;

```
String ln="á€á€­á€•á€¹á€•á€¶á€”á€²á€·";
    try {
        byte[] b = ln.getBytes("UTF-8");
        String s = new String(b, "US-ASCII");
        System.out.println(s);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

when I run it, it does not print Brumese, Is there a sloution for that ? Thanks

Comment: Why should this print "Burmese" it will be ever: "á€á€­á€•á€¹á€•á€¶á€”á€²á€·". Because you defined the string that way, then moved it to a byte array using UTF-8, which is still ""á€á€­á€•á€¹á€•á€¶á€”á€²á€·". Then you convert that UTF-8 byte array to us ASCI which is still ""á€á€­á€•á€¹á€•á€¶á€”á€²á€·"

Comment: @ReneM. In fact, this string coming from a json object

Comment: Then read the json in correct encoding.

Comment: @ReneM. I read it like "HttpEntity ent = response.getEntity(); text = EntityUtils.toString(ent,"UTF-8");" But it is still get strange chars

Comment: And is the response in UTF-8? Check the header

Comment: @ReneM. It comes with 'မြန်မာ့တန်း' string

Comment: Thet means nothing. The tool you used to view the json already read the bytes of the strem in his expected encoding, which resulted in this String. Without knowledge about response encoding no one can say what is the correct representation of that byte array. All your examples here are guesses from tools you use.

Comment: Instead of EntityUtils.toString(ent, "UTF-8"), use `EntityUtils.toString(ent)` with no charset.  That will [convert the response body to a String using the response's own charset](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString%28org.apache.http.HttpEntity%29).

Comment: @VGR again strange chars

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that the server is sending back content either with the wrong charset, or double-encoded.  If at all possible, you should get that fixed.

In the meantime, you have the right idea—converting the mis-encoded text to the correct charset.

Each character in your String was apparently supposed to be a *single byte* which was part of an UTF-8 byte sequence.  What you're actually seeing is each of those single bytes being treated as a character in the Windows [cp1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) charset, and converted to a Java char accordingly.

So, you first want to convert the chars from cp1252 back into the proper bytes:

```
byte[] b = ln.getBytes("cp1252");
```

Now you have a true UTF-8 byte sequence, which you can convert into the proper String:

```
String s = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
// In Java 6, you must use:
//String s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
```

You should never use US-ASCII if you are decoding, or trying to generate, Burmese characters, or any non-English characters.  ASCII consists of codepoints 0 through 127 only.

Comment: result on console: �?ိပ္ပံနဲ့

Comment: That is what you should see.  The first four characters in the original String do not correspond to valid UTF-8 bytes, since Burmese characters are encoded as three bytes in UTF-8, not two; that is why you see the "�?".  The rest are Burmese characters.  I don't speak the language, but Google Translate says it means "ranges from exchange."

Comment: but I mean how can I see chars like that pic: http://postimg.org/image/ch19nnenj/

Comment: That has nothing to do with your code.  You need a font that contains Burmese characters.  I'm sure a Google search will reveal a few.